# How to save JasperViewer to file/stream programmatically?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In our project we create reports and show it to users by `JasperViewer` `setVisible(true)` method. We need to have possibility to save this file on server programmatically (e.g. PDF file). Problem is that we cannot get File or stream from `JasperViewer` object. Any idea how to get java file or stream from JasperViewer inside java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save generated file then you can use

```
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"D:/report/"+REPORT_NAME+".pdf");
```